Why do these From<A> and From<B> implmentations cause a duplicate implementation error?
Context
I have a type Signal<T> and I would like to create two implementations for From<A> and From<B> for Signal<T>
Specifically I want to be able to create a Signal<T> from either a T or a function that gives a T. I have written some sample code below and here is a playground link to the same code.
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Signal<T: ?Sized> {
    _d: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Signal<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { _d: PhantomData }
    }
}

impl<T, F> From<F> for Signal<T> where F: Fn() -> T + 'static {
    fn from(f: F) -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for Signal<T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}



fn main() {
    let a = Signal::<u8>::from(5);
    let b = Signal::<u8>::from(|| 5);
}

This yields the following compiler error:
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<_>` for type `Signal<_>`
  --> src/lib.rs:19:1
   |
13 | impl<T, F> From<F> for Signal<T> where F: Fn() -> T + 'static {
   | ------------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
19 | impl<T> From<T> for Signal<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Signal<_>`

I understand that the compiler thinks that these two implementations overlap, however I cannot see any way to construct a counterexample type.
I think that this needs specialization, but I don't really understand why, or how to write similar code using the proposed specialization RFC in nightly.
Question
What is a counterexample type for the proposed code? Can this code be altered to allow both trait impls today? If not, how would this code be written assuming that the specialization RFC were to be merged today?

This won't be possible with the current proposed specialization because neither impl is more specific, the RFC even includes a similar counterexample:

// Overlap: instantiate T = &'a U.
impl<T> Bar<T> for T {}         // Neither is more specific
impl<'a, T, U> Bar<T> for &'a U
    where U: Bar<T> {}


Providing a counterexample is pointless, the compiler doesn't check to find one, it only checks if the types permit one. But here is one for entertainment anyways:
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
struct Foo;
impl FnOnce<()> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, (): ()) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}
impl FnMut<()> for Foo {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, (): ()) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
}
impl Fn<()> for Foo {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (): ()) -> Foo {
        Foo
    }
} 


Ah, the counterexample helps me understand here. I forget that you can just implement Fn(). it's just another trait.

would negative bounds let you write this? i.e. could you negative bound the second impl to make it mutually exclusive? I'm just trying to figure out what if any forward path within the language might exist eventually.

Possibly, but they are not a thing nor are they planned as far as I know. Negative bounds can make implementing a trait a breaking change, the consensus is we don't want that.

:-/ this is why I hesistated to add the counterexample to begin with, it does not matter if Fn is a trait that "you can just implement" the fact that the types check out is enough to make the implementations overlapping. I.e. even if Fn was unimplementable, there's nothing in the bound that makes this not overlapping and hence the implementations would conflict.

I understand, I was just doing some digging on negative bounds. I was under the impression that it was a planned go forward that I was just unfamiliar with in this case. The counterexample helped me personally though.
So to summarize, The types do overlap, because there is no limitation that a type T cannot impl Fn() -> T.
The ways to correct this would be to:
A: Have some future specialization case that is currently not supported in the specialization RFC.
B: Have a negative trait bound on the second impl, which is currently not planned because it causes many issues with forward compat.
